# SwipeMenuListView views are not consistent in android

Tags: android, xml, swipe-gesture

I used SwipeMenuListView from [github](https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView) It works but Views are not consistent as in the picture

[image]

Activity layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.robo.lolita.swipemenurecyclerview.MainActivity">
        <com.baoyz.swipemenulistview.SwipeMenuListView
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

this is simple layout swipe menu layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/count"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

```
  SwipeMenuCreator creator = new SwipeMenuCreator() {
            public void create(SwipeMenu menu) {
                SwipeMenuItem deleteItem = new SwipeMenuItem(
                        getApplicationContext());
                deleteItem.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb(0xF9,
                        0x3F, 0x25)));
                deleteItem.setWidth(dp2px(90));
                deleteItem.setIcon(R.drawable.camera_icn);
                menu.addMenuItem(deleteItem);
```

I need to attach delete button to the item of listview on Swipe. this swipe menu with delete button. i want to delete the item on clicking the delete button but views are inconsistent in swipemenulistview. Any help to acheive this. Well i cannot do swipe to dismiss and i know we should not mimic the UI of other platforms. but this is the requirement .